# print(len(list_a)) is printed as two but print(list_a) is printed as []

Tags: python, numpy

I'm modifying a python code to see lane detection image on a pygame surface. It works fairly ok but occasionally I see  error messages which comes from the function below(I added two prints for debug).

```
def display_lines(image, lines):
    line_image = np.zeros_like(image)
    if lines is not None:
        print('len of lines:',len(lines))
        print(lines)
        for line in lines:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = line
            cv2.line(line_image, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255,0,0), 4)
    return line_image
```

When it's normal, it prints like this:

```
len of lines: 2
[[ 251  720  998    0]
 [1026  720  281    0]]
```

When there are errors, the error message is like this:

```
len of lines: 2 
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./automatic_control.py", line 758, in <lambda>
    self.sensor.listen(lambda image: CameraManager._parse_image(weak_self, image))
  File "./automatic_control.py", line 803, in _parse_image
    line_image = display_lines(lane_image, averaged_lines)
  File "./automatic_control.py", line 700, in display_lines
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

In the error case, `print(lines)` prints just `[]` but why did it print `2` for `print(len(lines))`? What could be the problem?

Comment: Can't tell without a [mcve], but my guess is that `lines` is the string `'[]'`.

Comment: @Julien: If it were, the error message would have said `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`, rather than `0 values`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lines` is not a list. `lines` is a NumPy array. Those are completely different types that you *really need* to understand the difference between if you're going to work with NumPy.

In the case that's confusing you, `lines` is a 2x0 array. The `len` of a NumPy array is the length of its first dimension, so `lines` has length 2, but it still contains 0 elements.

I would have expected such an array to print as

```
[[]
 []]
```

but apparently it prints as `[]`.

For a more informative display, you should print the array's `repr`, which would show something like

```
array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=something)
```

Comment: I see, I tested a = np.ndarray([[],[]])  print(a)  and print(len(a)). len(a) is 2 and a is printed as just []. I'll have to consider cases where no lane is detected now..